# ADFS Redirect_URI not working how can redirect another url?

Tags: javascript, c#, saml, adfs

I have configure two SAML Assertion Consumer under the relying party as below:

[Configuration Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwwZB.jpg)

Now when i initiate login url (as redirect_uri) in query string it always redirect to the default page instead of the second url so how can i redirect to url which is on 1st index ?

below the url that i am initiate for login:
https://fs.in.rptech.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon?loginToRp=https://10.1.3.38:9090&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4435

Answer (score 0):

SAML supports embedding additional information into [RelayState](https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/saml/) for each authentication request.

To embed RelayState into an IDP-initiated login request with ADFS, you will need to [encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/jj127245(v=ws.10)#configuration-required) your desired RelayState and SPID. [An online tool](https://jackstromberg.com/adfs-relay-state-generator/) to generate IDP-initiated login link is also available.

Notice that it is [not possible](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/ed74980c-84c8-44cd-b182-b4ff88079d4b/ad-fs-40-and-relaystate-along-with-logintorp-not-working-using-idpinitiatedsignon-page?forum=ADFS) to embed RelayState when you are using the loginToRp parameter.

You will need to [Set-AdfsProperties -EnableRelayStateForIdpInitiatedSignOn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsproperties) in your ADFS server first.

And your application needs to retrieve the RelayState attribute from SAMLReponse and do the actual redirection.